# Fetch console logs error code selenium js

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, monitoring, synthetic

the following is my code in selenium JS, at the last step, I want to fetch the error code from the browser console, I need to check, there shouldn't be any 504 error code in the browser console for the current page.

```
driver.get(M_URL)
    .then(() => {
        return driver.findElement(By.xpath('//input[@id="UserName"]'))
            .then(el => el.sendKeys(USERNAME));
    })
    .then(() => {
        return driver.findElement(By.xpath('//input[@id="Password"]'))
            .then(el => el.sendKeys(PASSWORD));
    })
    .then(() => {
        return driver.findElement(By.xpath('//button[text()="Login"]'))
            .then(el => el.click());
    })
    .then(() => {
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath('//h3[text()[contains(.,"Publisher")]]')).click()
        .then(() => log('Publisher page is rendered'));
    })
    .then(() => log('check 504 error code in browser console'));
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how can you do it

```
require('chromedriver');

const path = require('path');
const wd = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

var builder = new wd.Builder();
var options = new chrome.Options();
var prefs = new wd.logging.Preferences();
var driver;

prefs.setLevel(wd.logging.Type.BROWSER, wd.logging.Level.ALL);
options.setLoggingPrefs(prefs);

driver = builder
    .forBrowser(wd.Browser.CHROME)
    .setChromeOptions(options)
    .build();

driver
    .get(`file://${path.resolve(__dirname, './page.html')}`)
    .then(() => driver.manage().logs().get(wd.logging.Type.BROWSER))
    .then((logs) => {
        console.log(logs);
    })
    .then(() => driver.quit());
```

more about it [here](https://gist.github.com/customcommander/fefa2e1a921d2646f5257f86a4caa18a)